# Temporarily kill an activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Is there any way to kill an activity when the user leaves the application and resume it once the person starts the application again? Kind of like 
  finish(); .

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: I suggest reading the [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html) developer docs.

Answer (score 0):

On the onPause method use SharedPreferences to save the app state, then destroy the activity, then when the app is relaunched restore the state on the onCreate